# How to get all child values nested under a parent node in firebase database c#

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I am making a Xamarin Forms app (c#) using Firebase Database to store data. I am trying to get all of the child node data from this tree:

Users:

- User 1

  - User name
  - User email
- User 2

  - User name
  - User email

So essentially, getting the values "User 1" and "User 2" in this case.  How would this be possible?  I know that it is possible to get the "User name" and "User email" if you know what the User 1 value is, but how would I do this to get the child node name while maintaining this data structure?

Please let me know if there is something that I need to clarify or be more specific about.

Comment: You add database table structure and data content example.

Comment: @vm I'm not really sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1, a local model class:**

```
    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

**Step 2, a helper class:**

```
    public static class FirebaseHelper
    {
        FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("<YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING>");

        public async Task<List<User>> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return (await firebase
              .Child("Users")
              .OnceAsync<User>())
              .Select(item => new User
              {
                  Name  = item.Object.name,
                  Email = item.Object.email
              }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

**Step 3, fetch the list:**

```
    var userList = await FirebaseHelper.GetAllUsers();
```

---

### Update for fetching the node name

**Step 1, a local model class:**

```
    public class User
    {
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

**Step 2, the method in the helper class:**

```
    public async Task<List<User>> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return (await firebase
          .Child("Users")
          .OnceAsync<User>())
          .Select(item => new User
          {
              UserID = item.Key,    //the node name is here
              Name   = item.Object.name,
              Email  = item.Object.email
          }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Will this get the child node name or just allow me to retrieve the name and email info? Thank you!

Comment: In Step 2, the return type of ```GetAllUsers``` is ```List<User>```, so you'll get the local user object list and can retrieve the name and email. Btw, you can find more examples by searching "c# firebase crud".

Comment: Would I use the listview in XAML to display this, with the list being the ItemSource?  Because when I am trying out the code, it doesn't really display this way.  When I debug by seeing if the list is null, it says that it is not.  But when I try to display it nothing comes up.

Comment: It seems like this answer would work best if I was trying to get all of the Email and Name info (please let me know if I am mistaken), but what I am trying to do is get the string of what that data is nested under.  So I am trying to make the code to, in this example, return "User 1", "User 2".

Comment: For the display issue, that would be the problem of either value binding or triggering OnPropertyChanged, which is another question. For "User 1", "User 2", you are right, I didn't get the node name for you, probably edit the answer later. (Or you can also add a new value with same string as a child)

Comment: Yeah, for my particular use case my tree is going to get more complicated in the future and also if I know how to get the child names it will help me with other parts of the app so I will keep this question open for different solutions.  Thank you so much for answering though :)

Comment: One more line with ```item.Key```, you can do it. Answer updated.